# How do I fit my model within the specific dimensions?

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, subdivision-surface

This is the requirements for the axes:
[image]

And this is my model with its dimensions:
[image]

How do I make it so that the model fits exactly within said dimensions, I never really dealt with it when I was learning so think now is the right time.

[image]